# Unbalanced dataset split

Tags: validation, machine-learning, classification

What is the best technique for unbalanced `dataset`?

I have a `dataset` of 11967 instances where the number of positive labels is 139 and the number of negative labels is 11828 .

How to split the `dataset` for testing (before or after the technique)?

Comment: What kind of data is this? And why just testing? (what do you do for training?)

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by the kind of the data. Regarding the training, I can handle the training data by doing either under sampling or over sampling, but also the testing data is unbalanced, so I am afraid that might affect the evaluation of the model as well.

Comment: Define "best". By what measure?

Answer (score 4):

There are few good ways to handle imbalanced dataset:

**Undersampling**: it means taking the less number of majority class (in your case negative labels so that the new dataset will be balanced).

**Oversampling**: it means replicating the data of minority class (positive labels) in order to balance the dataset.

There is also a third way of handling imbalanced dataset, i.e. **smote**. Feel free to check out this link:  https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/09/this-machine-learning-project-on-imbalanced-data-can-add-value-to-your-resume/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you should use **stratify** method in sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split. If you set this statify = 'y' (y is the label of your data set), this will divide your data in such a way that train and test sets contain equal percentage of positive and negative samples. This is highly useful in unbalanced datasets. Instead of random division of dataset, it would consider the labels while dividing dataset into two parts.

Here is the sample code:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size =0.2,statify = y)
```

Refer to documentation for more information:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: You misspelled "stratify" .. Be careful when you copy/paste!

Answer (score 1):

The standard method for splitting the dataset using sklearn is given below:

```
#splitting the datasets into training and validation sets (60% training)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xTrain, xVald, yTrain, yVald = train_test_split(Xs, y, train_size=0.60, random_state = 2)
```

where Xs and y are the predictors and response variables.

As you mentioned, your dataset has the imbalanced distribution of the classes. This distribution does not allow you to build the predictive model as the model treat your rare event (positive level) as the random noise and couldn't predict well for the new data set.

You may have to upsample the rare event to make it balanced in the distribution before building any predictive model. If you want to stick on the original distribution then you can run random forest model which works well for the imbalanced data as well. For more information, please see the following link:
https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes

If you want to upsample to your data, then you can try this:

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
# Separate majority and minority classes
df_majority = df[df.pos_neg==0] #I classified negative class as '0'
df_minority = df[df.pos_neg==1]

# Upsample minority class
df_minority_upsampled = resample(df_minority, 
                                 replace=True,       # sample with replacement
                                 n_samples=11828,    # to match majority class
                                 random_state=123)   # reproducible results

# Combine majority class with upsampled minority class
df_upsampled = pd.concat([df_majority, df_minority_upsampled])

# Display new class counts
df_upsampled.value_counts()
# 1    11828
# 0    11828
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am kind of confusing whether or not to use a class weight on the minority class as in scikit learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html  after up-sampling or under-sampling my data.